# Truncate media_storage_file_storage table

Tags: magento2, database

The table 'media_storage_file_storage' is very big.

Can I truncate this table if I use "File System" as "Media Storage"?

Answer (score 1):

As per this [Doc](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/media-storage-database.html#:%7E:text=Use%20a%20database%20for%20media%20storage&text=In%20the%20left%20panel%2C%20expand,configuration%20at%20the%20global%20level.&text=Set%20Media%20Storage%20to%20Database,database%20you%20want%20to%20use.) I think you don't have to do anything. Just change the storage system and click on the Synchronize button below

Then also take a backup of the entire site and set-up on the local system and do it. And see if it working or not.

Thanks
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

**Use a database for media storage**

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to Stores > Settings > Configuration.
2. In the left panel, expand Advanced and choose System.
3. In the upper-left corner, set Store View to Default Config to apply the configuration at the global level.
4. Expand Expansion selector the Storage Configuration for Media section and do the following:
   [image]

   Advanced configuration - storage configuration for media
   Storage Configuration for Media (Database)

   ```
   Set Media Storage to Database.

   Set Select Media Database to the database you want to use.

   Click Synchronize to transfer the existing media to the newly selected database.

   Enter the Environment Update Time in seconds.
   ```
5. When complete, click Save Config.